# Cannot create AlertDialog: AppCompat error

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-appcompat

I am trying to create an AlertDialog like this:

```
counterButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

        new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setTitle("Delete entry")
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // continue with delete
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // do nothing
                    }
                })
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .show();  // <------- crashes here

        return true;
    }
});
```

I am using an AppCompat theme for my app.  Here is the `application` element of my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

As you can see, my theme is set to `@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`.
But whenever I am running my app it crashes with the following error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

I googled a lot and found a few similar questions at SO but didn't manage to solve the problem. I am using an `AppCompat` theme, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it possible that int he MainActivity you setup another theme in the xml layout?

Comment: @Jaythaking, thanks! I just checked. I am not specifying any theme in my `activity_main.xml`

Comment: What `context` are you passing into your `AlertDialog.Builder`? Is it your Activity or `getApplicationContext()`?

Comment: @ianhanniballake: I am passing `getApplicationContext()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your theme is related to your `Activity`, you must pass it as the `context` to `AlertDialog.Builder` - `getApplicationContext()` has no theme attached to it which is why you are getting an error.

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

as error said

```
You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme
```

then you will create style extend AppTheme

```
!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"/>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->



<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Isn't that the same as using `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">` directly?

Comment: yea but make it in each activity

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I just tried it and am still getting the same error :(

Comment: did your MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity

Comment: Yes it does, ianhanniballake found the problem. But thanks anyways!